# PHP: Convert back to time() format from form select

Tags: php

Not sure if this has already been answered or not, but I did do a google search and couldn't really find anything useful.

---

I have the following html code (as an example) which has a form select field for month, day, year, hour, and minute (second is always 00) and I need to convert that back to time() format on form submit.  How would I do this with php?

```
<select name="month">
    <option value="01">January</option>
    <option value="02">February</option>
    <option value="03">March</option>
    ...
</select>

<select name="day">
    <option value="01">1</option>
    <option value="02">2</option>
    <option value="03">3</option>
    ...
</select>

<select name="year">
    <option value="2014">2014</option>
    <option value="2015">2015</option>
    ...
</select>

<select name="hour">
    <option value="00">12am</option>
    <option value="01">1am</option>
    <option value="02">2am</option>
    <option value="03">3am</option>
    <option value="12">12pm</option>
    <option value="13">1pm</option>
    ...
</select>

<select name="minute">
    <option value="01">1</option>
    <option value="02">2</option>
    <option value="03">3</option>
    ...
</select>

<!-- second is always 00 -->
```

Note: The values of each select can change if they need to.  Not sure what format they need to be in to make this work efficiently.

Comment: andwhere is your php?

Comment: I have no clue how to do it, so I wouldn't know where to start with the php.

Comment: I don't know the conversion method to transform this back to time() format.

Comment: `mktime`? Or `DateTime::setDate` & `DateTime::setTime` if you like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [`strtotime()`](https://www.php.net/strtotime) and the [`DateTime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class.

```
<?php
$date = $_POST['year'] . '-' . $_POST['month'] . '-' . $_POST['day'];
$time = $_POST['hour'] . ':' . $_POST['minute'];

// Simple way to get a Unix timestamp from a date string
$timestamp = strtotime($date . ' ' . $time);

// To do more modifications to the date, you should use the DateTime class
$dateObj = new DateTime($date . ' ' . $time);
$dateObj->modify('+1 year'); // Adds a year to the date
$timestamp = $dateObj->format('U'); // Returns the date as a Unix timestamp
```

Comment: are my values okay for this method?  Month: xx  Day: xx  Year: xxxx   Hour: xx   Minute: xx ??

Comment: Yup, `strtotime()` (or any DateTime from string method) is pretty robust.  The default format is `YYYY-mm-dd HH:ii:ss` which is your format exactly.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Be22G/1/  the code here is returning the following error: `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (2015-03- 02:02) at position 7 (-): Unexpected character' in /home/****/public_html/datetime.php:10 Stack trace: #0 /home/****/public_html/datetime.php(10): DateTime->__construct('2015-03- 02:02') #1 {main} thrown in /home/****/public_html/datetime.php on line 10`

Comment: Sorry @kdjernigan, `$_POST['date']` should be `$_POST['day']`.  This can be debugged by seeing that we passed `2015-03- 02:02` (it is missing the day).

Comment: yeah I JUST saw that as well.  I saw it in your post but forgot to change that in the code.  Thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 3):

```
$time = DateTime::createFromFormat(
    'Y-m-d H:i:s',
    sprintf("%d-%d-%d %d:%d:%d",
        intval($_POST['year']),
        intval($_POST['month']),
        intval($_POST['day']),
        intval($_POST['hour']),
        intval($_POST['minute']),
        0
    )
);
```

You now have a DateTime object, to get a unix timestamp do:

```
$timestamp = $time->getTimestamp();
```

Comment: is this the same format as time() ?  Just wanted to check because my code is using time() internally.

Comment: Doh, ment to concat those :) Will fix

Answer (score 1):

Use [strtotime](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.strtotime.php) function.

```
echo strtotime("10 September 2000"); // output 968569200 of unix timestamp
```